# how to use object spread syntax in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I started using object spread syntax to safely make a copy of the object while following immutability principles.

I want to use it in chrome developer console - how to do this:

[image]

Comment: `Object.assign()` will do a shallow copy of an object.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508).

Comment: Object spread is a [*proposal*](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) and is not available in the current stable version of Chrome.

Answer (score 19):

You can enable the javascript experiments flag on: **chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony**
to enable web pages to use experimental JavaScript features including the Rest / Spread.

[image]

Comment: Im starting to learn es7- Will I be able to use es7 features in chrome dev console if I turn on this flag??

Answer (score 5):

Object spread is available in all modern browsers ([since Chrome 60](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5657004848709632)) and can be used like this:

```
{...{foo: 'bar'}, john: 'doe'}
```

And will return: `{foo: "bar", john: "doe"}`

Comment: @Aequitas Works for me. Try this: `{...{foo: 'bar'}}`

Comment: Ah my bad, it's the array spread that doesn't work (sometimes): `let a = ...['foo']`, fails with unexpected token. But `console.log(...['foo'])` will work just fine

Comment: @Aequitas You must spread into another array: `[...['foo'], 'bar']`

Answer (score -2):

`...` is not an operator (at least not in the sense the ECMAScript spec uses the term "operator"). It is actually called "spread syntax", or "rest syntax".

Comment: [compat-table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-object_spread_properties) says that Chrome 58 has support for object spread, but its hidden by flag

Comment: chrome://version is revealing that the current official build for windows is 55.something;
might have to install canary to try this

Comment: @Robsonsjre Please make an effort to be more friendly. If OP mentions "..." as an operator, don't just say that it isn't one. You could have said that it's actually called "spread syntax" or "rest syntax", provide some refs/articles. On the other hand, more of the same half information. It's not in stable Chrome but there are flags to enable it.